# Change a mock private property

Tags: php, phpunit

Since Reflection Class throws a ReflectionException if parent private property is get (http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getproperty.php#117476), which is the best way to read/write private properties of a Mock object?

This is a simplified version of the affected code:

```
class SomeClass{
    private $some_value = false;
}

function setValue($class, $name, $value)
{
    $reflection = new ReflectionClass($class);
    $property = $reflection->getProperty($name);
    $property->setAccessible(true);
    $property->setValue($class, $value);
}

$mock = $this->getMockBuilder('SomeClass')->getMock();

setValue($mock, 'some_value', true);
```

Comment: Why are you trying to read/write values of a private mock?  Just use the mock builder to specify what gets returned from the public methods and don't worry about the private values.

Comment: Lets say that I have a private property with a getter, and I want to test that getter. I should set manually a value into that property and check if the getter returns it properly. Does that make sense?

Comment: Not really.  You don't need to mock the class in that scenario.  You would instantiate the class and call the getter making sure that the proper value gets returned.  The initial value would be set via the constructor or a setter.  No mock is required.  Having to get into the internals of your class makes your tests much less useful for future refactoring.

Comment: What if the getter/setter validates the output/input calling another function?

Comment: That gets tested along with your getter and setter, as they are part of the expected functionality for your class.  You don't want to test _functions_, you want to test _behaviors_.  Checking that your code does what it is supposed to.

Comment: What about code coverage?

Comment: What about it? The other function that your getter/setter calls get exercised with the getter and setter tests.  So your code coverage will be fine.  If you have 100% of your behaviors tested, you should have 100% code coverage.